# DataStudio : BigQuery & Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, looker-studio

How to use standard SQL queries on Google Data Studio using a BigQuery Data Source ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific, and provide more details?

Comment: The Data Studio team is working hard to integrate with standard SQL in BigQuery. If you haven't already, it may be useful to the team if you submit feedback by clicking on the "three dot" dropdown at the top right of the Data Studio web page and send feedback about the type of analysis that you would like to be able to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Data Studio supports #standardSQL now!

Just check the appropriate box when inserting your query.

[image]