# BigQuery view as a data source in Google DataStudio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am getting this error, while trying to use a BigQuery view data source in Google Data Studio:

**Error Details: There's a query error. Cannot reference a SQL view in a Legacy SQL query.**

[image]

So, I checked the view's info and the "Use Legacy SQL" is false:

[image]

The view is working fine in BigQuery, but it seems that Google Data Studio is running the query in "Legacy mode" instead of "SQL Standard Dialect mode".  If this is the problem, how can I change this setting in the Data Studio?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/q/42064616/5221944 - look at comments and answer

Comment: You need to use the custom query option (e.g. with `SELECT * FROM YourViewName`) for the time being, which lets you specify to use standard SQL.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard it is working now, by using Google Datastudio "Custom Query" option and not the view.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - any chance you could promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: I added a proper answer now. When the Data Studio team announces support for standard SQL views as data sources, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the custom query option for the time being, which lets you specify to use standard SQL. Your query can simply be:

```
SELECT * FROM YourViewName;
```

My understanding at the time of this writing is that the Data Studio team is still working on support for data sources created from standard SQL views.